# Log parser process is not allowing log4j to rotate the logs

Tags: log4j, logparser, logrotate

I wrote a log parser that constantly reads the log file gets specific lines from the log and writes them into database. Logs are generated via LOG4J. Logs are being rotated when they reach specific size. My problem is that my log parser process is not allowing log4j to rotate the logs.

Can you please advice on this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner solution would be to use `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` for the log statements that you want in the database, and have log4j insert them directly.